# controlling the size of the slider on a scrollbar

Tags: qt, user-interface

I'm writing a UI that can be panned with a horizontal scrollbar, but also panned and zoomed independently (like an non-linear editor's clips window). This is a Qt based UI, and I don't need to consider height, simply length.

The panning by itself, I think I can handle, but not the zoom. The issue is how to control the size of the slider/grip widget on the scrollbar. When zoomed into the UI, it should shrink, the reverse when zooming out. The size of the slider should reflect the zoom (i.e. if I've zoomed in to see 10% of the view, the slider should be about 10% the size of the scrollbar, or as close to it as possible).

The problem is that Qt doesn't seem to let me control the size of the slider directly, I can only control it indirectly via a combination of the min/max values and the large step count, and this is where I am (embarrassingly) stuck. I can't seem to scale these factors and preserve my scrolling with the bar. Has anyone else done this kind of thing before?

Comment: What is the control your using to display this data? And also how exactly are you handling the zoom in/out. Can you show those bits of code?

Comment: It's a panel in Maya, a 3D modeling and animation package. It allows you to embed some of its panel UIs into custom UI (using PyQt or PySide). In my case, I'm using the clipEditor (if you know the package). You can listen to panel events and how I ascertain zoom is to divide the frame range the panel has by the full frame range (which I know), and take the inverse of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry,

Haven't used Maya myself..

If your wondering about just the slider(thumb) size, it is as you said controlled with the setMaximum(), setMinimum() functions.

If I get your requirement correctly, you want the thumb size to correspond to the zoom level

- 1000% zoom as in zoom factor = 10 -> thumb size is 10% of scrollbar
- 100% zoom where in no scrollbar.

I'm assuming you can calculate the zoom factor(say K) which would be the scale of your zoom and you can control the scrollbar Min/Max/Current values via Maya

Always in this case have scrollbar Minimum at 0.

- Set the maximum of the scrollbar to be the width of the content your showing when zoom factor is 1(k- current):1(original). Save this maximum value for future uses as say (Z)

^^ this will give you no scrollbar at zoom factor 1 if your content fills the available width exactly.

- Next when your zoom factor changes to say K = 2 (200% scale).

  1. Get old zoom factor(`Y`) by calculating `scrollbar->maximum() / Z`.
  2. Set New [Scrollbar Maximum](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractslider.html#maximum-prop) as `K * Z`.
  3. Set New [Scrollbar value](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractslider.html#value-prop) as `scrollbar->value() * K / Y`.

^^ This now will in-turn set the size of the scrollbar thumb to the size your looking for(zoom factor)

Just note that this assumes your content at zoom factor 1 requires no scrollbar and fits the available width fully.

If this is not the case and width of the control showing your content is re sizable the result of above logic would imply that at a zoom factor of say 10 means the thumb will be at 10% of its size when zoom factor was at 1. Hence size of thumb will not be 10% of scrollbar but 10% of itself at 100% scale

Comment: Finally implemented it right, thanks! This was the way to go.